# Android add background behind imagebutton, edittext, imagebutton

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext, imagebutton

I'm trying to add a footer containing an imagebutton, an textview and another imagebutton to my activity (I want to make an app like whatsapp and it should nearly look the same). I have tried many ways, but all didnt work.
I tried to make a footer like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/chatBottom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:background="#D8D8D8"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/emojiButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/emoji_button"
    android:background="#D8D8D8"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/emojiButton"
        android:background="@drawable/textfield_multiline_activated_holo_dark"
        android:hint="" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#D8D8D8"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/action_send_message" />
```

and add it using include in xml or via addView() in java, but nothing worked properly. Most important is that the footer has its on background colour (always when I tried to set a colour to the layout where the footer is in, the whole activity got this colour) and that the textview resizes automatically.

Best regards, Oliver

Comment: Have you tried making your footer it's own fragment?

Comment: Take a look at this link and give it a shot first, then come back with more specific questions.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html